# Restart server every 5 second before when the server does not receive a response from the client

Tags: java, serversocket

I want my server to restart every 5 seconds before when the server does not receive a response from the client  and right now it just closes help pliz just write the server restart code

```
class UDPServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            // create the server socket
            DatagramSocket ss = new DatagramSocket(1234);
            // array to store the data to get from client 
            byte indata[]=new byte[1024];
            System.out.println("Server worked 5 seconds");
            ss.setSoTimeout(5000);
            while(true) {
                try {
                    //create the datagram encapsulated packet 
                    DatagramPacket p2 = new DatagramPacket(indata,indata.length);
                    // server receive  the packet from client 
                    ss.receive(p2);
                    System.out.println("Messge received.");
                    // packet data convert in sting
                    String s2 = new String (p2.getData()); 
                    // print the received data on screen(console)
                    System.out.println(s2);
                }
                catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    // timeout exception.
                    System.out.println("Time excepted");
                    ss.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Server restart");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your closing the server socket whenever you have a socket timeout exception. A socket timeout exception occurs when you have no responses in the specified time frame. You set the timeout to 5000ms, so if no one connects to the server it is closed.

```java
try{
    // your code here
}catch (SocketTimeoutException e) { // <-- This block of code runs when the timeout is reached
    // timeout exception.
    System.out.println("No requests yet.");
    ss.close(); // <-- This closes the socket
}
```

You probably want to have two catch blocks. One will handle the case of a timeout, and the other will handle other exceptions.

```java
try{
    DatagramPacket p2 = new DatagramPacket(indata,indata.length);
    // server receive  the packet from client 
    ss.receive(p2);
    System.out.println("Messge received.");
    // packet data convert in sting
    String s2 = new String (p2.getData()); 
    // print the received data on screen(console)
    System.out.println(s2);
}catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // timeout exception.
    System.out.println("No requests yet.");
}catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Server Socket threw an exception!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I want to solve the task in russian this (5 task) opennet.ru/docs/RUS/socket/node15.html in english this task: Write a program that asks the user for an IP address, port number and text string, sends a string to the specified address using the UDP protocol, waits for a response, and displays it on the screen. If within 5 sec. the answer is not received, the program starts its execution again. Thank you for help but your answer is false